# Having a svelte store per component instance while able to access it globaly

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

So I have this parent component containing multiple children components like so:

```
<script>
 import { derived, writable } from 'svelte/store';
 import {childStore } from 'child.svelte';
 export const parentStore = writable<parent>({
     childs:[
     //here I'd like to have all the children's instances stores in the array with the child's index as key.
    ]
 });
    export const calculatedStuff = derived(parent, () => {
        //process data from the parent AND each child's store
    });
</script>

{#each $parent.children as child, childIndex}
 <Child {childIndex} />
{/each}
```

And the child component like so :

```
<script context="module" lang="ts">

 import { derived, writable } from 'svelte/store';
 export const childStore = writable<child>({
     // data specific to the child's instance
 });
    export const calculatedChild = derived(child, () => {
        // process data from the child's store
    });
</script>

<script lang="ts">
    export let childIndex: number;
</script>
<div id={childIndex} class="child" />
```

How can I create a separate store for each child instance (preferably inside the child file) and nest them inside the parent's store ?

Here is a REPL for convenience :

https://svelte.dev/repl/94a5ca4e85ee40c182c6ab41355635cb?version=3.59.1

Comment: The `<script context="module">` content will be shared by all component instances. The title says *access it globaly* but from the question it only needs to be accessed inside the parent? Is there a different part that's not described in the question? The logic might be done without stores and would avoid the need to use get to access the child store value inside the derived calculation in parent like this https://svelte.dev/repl/bae51bbe1e934b24ac2d9e7291cfcd0f?version=3.59.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you must have in mind is that you cannot create children based on data provided by the future children, which is what I think you were trying to do with your example REPL, which brings me to the next points:

1. If you provide a REPL, make sure it works up to the point where you are stuck.
2. Svelte REPL doesn't support TypeScript, so creating scripts with `lang="ts"` doesn't work.

Having said that, look at [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/99435e131faa4a6e80a52fea257c0167?version=3.59.1).

Basically, what needs to be done is this:

1. The child component creates its own store and exports it.  In the sample REPL I provide, the store is `childStore`.
2. The parent creates children based on something **other** than data created by children because, well, the children are not yet created.  It is the "egg or chicken" dilemma.
3. You use an array variable in the parent to obtain references to the created children using `bind:this`.
4. You access the children's stores by using the reference array, the child's index and then `.childStore`.  Example:  `children[0].childStore` returns the store for the first child.

Now, in order to subscribe to changes in the children's stores from the parent, you must wait for children creation to be complete.  As seen in the REPL I provided, you may use `onMount` in the parent side.  The parent's `onMount` event fires after the children are mounted.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this you usually would use a context.

- [`setContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) in the parent, containing a store/object that the children can register with
- [`getContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-getcontext) in the child and add own data to said context

Usually some kind of store is used to preserve reactivity as contexts do not provide that by default.